# When a SQL DELETE query times out, what happens with the data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

If I were to run a `DELETE FROM some_table`, and that were to timeout, what happens to the data?

The way I see it, one of two things might happen:

- The data is deleted up to the point where the query times out, so if there were 1,000,000 entries in the database and the first 500,000 were deleted, they'd stay deleted. The database now contains half as many as it did before the query was run.
- The data is deleted, the query times out, the data is rolled back (I would guess from the logs made by `DELETE`?). The database now contains the exact same data it started with.

Both seem logical. Would one happen 100% of the time? Or is this dependent on some settings I'm unaware of? Note that I'm not asking about the viability of the `DELETE`, I realize that `TRUNCATE` would likely be opportune. This is purely out of curiosity of how timeout functions with `DELETE`.

Comment: mysql is an ACID database. individual query statements are atomic - they either finish completely, or they don't do anything at all.

Comment: @Marc: Strictly speaking, it depends on the engine being used.

Comment: When *timeout* means the transaction is aborted then the DELETE will be rolled back.

Comment: Don't tag it with MySQL if your question is specifically about SQL Server.

Comment: What exactly happens also depends on who is timing out.  If the client times out, but the server is unaware of it, you can have an orphaned uncommitted delete transaction that stays around for a while.  Depending on how your database is configured, this can cause other sessions to be unable to read or write the table's data until the server realizes it needs to rollback that operation.

Comment: I think if it is timeout, it will be rollback. so you will have 100,000 records as it is. I also think that whenever you have that issue just do the rollback so you are not halfway of deleting your records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Oracle, SQL Server,MySQL, PostgreSQL databases follows ACID properties. Hence whenever **`delete`** statement shows timed-out it must get rolled back.
You can get overview of ACID from the this [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/aa480356.aspx).